# Computing localizations in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization

I am trying to find a way to easily compute localisations of the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ ($n>1$). Is there any general result for this? I found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2312286) that when the multiplicative subset is $S=\{1,b,b^2,\dots\}$ and the prime factorization of $n$ is $n = \prod p_i^{l_i}$ then
$$S^{−1}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) \cong \prod_{p_i \nmid b} \mathbb{Z}/p_i^{l_i}\mathbb{Z}$$

Does this formula somehow generalize to an arbitrary multiplicative subset $S \subset \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: It might help to notice that localizing commutes with taking quotient, or, that localization is exact.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/757325/242) for a characterization for general Bezout domains.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4852148/326036) for a specialization when $S$ is the complement of a prime ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Chinese remainder theorem, we have a ring homomorphism
$$\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z\xrightarrow\sim\prod_i\Bbb Z/p_i^{l_i}\Bbb Z$$
By exactness of localization, we get an isomorphism:
$$S^{-1}(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)\xrightarrow\sim\prod_iS^{-1}(\Bbb Z/p_i^{l_i}\Bbb Z)$$
If $p_i$ divide some element in $S$, then $S^{-1}(\Bbb Z/p_i^{l_i}\Bbb Z)=\{0\}$, otherwise $S^{-1}(\Bbb Z/p_i^{l_i}\Bbb Z)\cong\Bbb Z/p_i^{l_i}\Bbb Z$.

If $T$ is the saturation of $S$, that's the set of all divisors of elements in $S$, then
$$S^{-1}(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)\cong\prod_{p_i\notin T}S^{-1}(\Bbb Z/p_i^{l_i}\Bbb Z)$$

Comment: Thanks, what is understood under the saturation of $S$?

Comment: @EinStone: The saturation of $S$ is the set of all divisors of elements in $S$.

Comment: Does this mean for example if $S=\{1,a,b,a^2,b^2,ab,\dots\}$ then $T=\{a,b\}$?

Comment: No, for example if $S=\{1,6,6^2,\ldots\}$, then $T=\{1,2,3,2\cdot 3,2^2,2^2\cdot 3,\ldots\}$.

Comment: Is $p_i \notin T$ equivalent to $p_i \nmid s$ $\forall s \in S$?

Comment: Yes, you are right.